# Liquibase: Ignite support

Tags: liquibase

Does Liquibase have any plans to support for Apache Ignite in the near future? 
I would like to use Liquibase along with Apache Ignite in a database proxy component that forms part of a micro-service architecture system we are building.

Answer (score 0):

Yours is the first I have heard of anyone asking. Your best hope is to write your own Ignite plugin. The effort required to implement something like that would depend heavily on whether or not the dialect of SQL it uses is similar to an existing dialect, and whether there is an existing JDBC driver for Ignite.

Comment: Ignite says it supports 'SQL ANSI-99'.  Does Liquibase support a generic SQL?

Comment: As far as I know (I am no longer with the company nor am I a current user of the library) there is no "generic SQL" provider for Liquibase. Creating one would not be that difficult I think, but it would need to either be raised as an issue in the Liquibase issue tracker (if you want the Liquibase team to develop it) or raised as a pull request if that is something you are willing to create.